# Eclipse hover over variable VS cout in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to debug the below code

```
result = 30 / 1000000000.0
rst = result * 1000000000
cout << "rst:" << rst << endl;
```

However, when I was trying to hover over the "rst" variable with eclipse to check on the value, eclipse will show me the value is 29.99999999999...6. But value printed in console with cout is 30. Why does this happen?In this case, which variable will be taken by the program to further proceed?

Comment: What is the datatype for rst?

Comment: Floating point numbers get all sorts of rounding errors. Eclipse is showing you the full, slightly wrong value and cout is rounding the value off further to make the print out prettier. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error

Comment: @RahulTripathi Both result and rst are double. :)

Comment: @QuestionKing Yes, which are floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, neither is giving you an exact decimal representation of the binary value stored in `rst`.
The output of `cout` is rounded and the value from Eclipse is either rounded/truncated or a value that would result in the same bit pattern when stored in a floating point variable.

I don't know the exact rules of IEEE floating point calculations, but due to the limited precision of floating point numbers, the exact decimal representation of any binary number (that has at least one fractional digit) **has to end with a five** as 1/2^n is always something like 0. ... 5 for any n>=0.

For one, this means that the precise result of 30/1000000000.0 cannot be accurately representetd by any floating point type (not even a double) and as a consequence, 30/1000000000.0*1000000000.0 is not an identity operation. (It's the same problem as e.g. dividing 1 by 3 in the decimal system)

Second, this also means that 29.99999999999...**6** cannot be an exact decimal representation of whatever is stored in rst.